# npm ignores "git+" during npm install

Tags: node.js, github, npm, npm-install

I have several dependencies in package.json specified as direct links to github repos:

```
"dependencies": {
  // omitted
  "gaze": "git+https://github.com/chebum/gaze.git",
}
```

When I checkout the project and perform `npm install`, a version of gaze is fetched from the global npm repo, not my github repo. I can confirm this by looking at the library source code.

If I later do `npm install git+https://github.com/chebum/gaze.git` I get a correct version of the library.

Why does npm override my package.json setting? I have no shrinkwrap file in the repo.

```
node -v 6.10.2
npm -v 3.10.10
```

Comment: This occurs even if you remove `node_modules` before installation?

Comment: @RyanZim yes. This happens when there is no node_modules folder present.

Comment: Perhaps try npm v4?